# While loops crashing, not adding words to the array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14

My program is supposed to ask the user to add a word that then will be added to the `string` array and after that, all words will be printed out. However, the program crashes in the while loop and strings don't get added to the array.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int counter = 0;
    bool isRunning = true;

    std::string listofthings[]
    {
    };

    while(isRunning)
    {
        char play;
        std::string word;
        std::cout << "Enter a word" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> word;
        listofthings[counter] = word;
        counter++;
        std::cout << "Word added! q to Quit, any other key to continue" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> play;
        if(play == 'q')
            isRunning = false;
    }

    int listnr = sizeof(listofthings)/sizeof(listofthings[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i < listnr; i++)
    {
        std::cout << listofthings[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did your debugger tell you anything useful?

Comment: What do you think that `std::string listofthings[]{};` does?

Comment: What is this `std::string listofthings[] {};`?

Comment: It compiles for you? because [it doesnt](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/729fcd6e2b7bd426) for me.

Comment: @Borgleader: It's a clang extension (a dangerous one)

Answer (score 5):

You defined `listofthings` as an empty C-style array (zero elements).

```
std::string listofthings[]
{
};
```

As [pointed by AndyG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435756/6022656), the language require that a size grather than zero, so your program is ill-formed.

So, when you use it,

```
listofthings[counter] = word;
```

the behavior is undefined and, in your case, the program crash.

Suggestion: transform `listofthings` in a `std::vector`

```
std::vector<std::string> listofthings;
```

and add elements using `emplace_back()` or `push_back()`

```
listofthings.emplace_back(std::move(word));
```

There is no need of `counter` and `listnr` (you can use `listofthings.size()`) and the print cycle become

```
for ( auto const & str : listofthings )
   std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

The statement

```
std::string listofthings[]
{
};
```

Is ill-formed C++ because the language requires that the initializer for an array contain more than zero elements ([dcl.init.aggr]):

> An array of unknown size initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer-list containing `n` *initializer-clauses*,
>   where `n` shall be greater than zero, is defined as having `n` elements.

You just got unlucky because it appears you're using clang, which allows an extension for zero-sized arrays. (clang will warn if you have [`-Wpedantic`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wpedantic) or [`-Wzero-length-array`](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wzero-length-array) turned on)

You should instead declare your array to have enough space for what you need, OR, [follow max66's advice and use a std::vector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47435514/27678)